# Find the smallest binary number without continous 1

Tags: java

So here is the thing.
I have to write code to show a binary number X's next smallest "code-X number" which is bigger than binary number X.
code-X number is a binary number which have no continuously 1. For example: 1100 is not a code X number because it has 11, and 1001001001 is a code-X number
Here is my code

```
String a = "11001110101010";
    String b = "";
    int d = 0;
    for(int i = a.length()-1; i>0;i--){
        if(a.charAt(i) == '1' && a.charAt(i-1)=='1'){
        while(a.charAt(i)=='1'){
            b = b + '0';
            if(i!=0){i--;}
            d++;
        }
        }
        b = b + a.charAt(i);
    }
    StringBuffer c = new StringBuffer(b);
    System.out.println(c.reverse());
```

I plan on copy the binary string to string b, replace every '1' which next i is '1' into '0' and insert an '1'
like:
1100 --->  10000
but i have no idea how to do it :)
May you help me some how? Thanks

Comment: Just a rough thought - what if you just put 0 between 11 ?

Comment: For your example, would the answer not just be `100000000000000`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , I realized that i didn't understand very well the question at the beginning. Hence, as you said, my post doesn't belong to answer. for that i delete it. good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  This handles arbitrary length bit strings.  The algorithm is as follows.

- Needed to conditionally modify last two bits to force a change if the number is not a codeEx number.  This ensures it will be higher.  Thanks to [John Mitchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8194026/john-mitchell) for this observation.
- Starting from the left, find the first group of 1's. e.g 0110
- If not at the beginning replace it with 100 to get 1000
- Otherwise, insert 1 at the beginning.
- In all cases, replace everything to the right of the grouping with 0's.

```
String x = "10000101000000000001000001000000001111000000000000110000000000011011";

System.out.println(x.length());
String result = codeX(x);

System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(result);


public static String codeX(String bitStr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bitStr);
    int i = 0;

   
    int len = sb.length();
    // Make adjust to ensure new number is larger than
    // original.  If the word ends in 00 or 10, then adding one will
    // increase the value in all cases.  If it ends in 01
    // then replacing with 10 will do the same.  Once done
    // the algorithm takes over to find the next CodeX number.
    if (s.equals("01")) {
        sb.replace(len - 2, len, "10");
    } else {
        sb.replace(len- 1, len, "1");
    }
    while ((i = sb.indexOf("11")) >= 0) {
        sb.replace(i, len, "0".repeat(len - i));
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.replace(i - 1, i + 2, "100");
        } else {
            sb.insert(i, "1");
        }
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
    i = str.indexOf("1");
    return i >= 0 ? str.substring(i) : str;
}
```

Prints

```
10000101000000000001000001000000001111000000000000110000000000011011
10000101000000000001000001000000010000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: that's not "a binary number X's _next_ smallest "code-X number" which is _bigger_ than binary number X"

Comment: Not much to understand, if you have binary number X, the post is about finding the "next number" that is higher than X, and has no consecutive ones in its bit pattern

Comment: apologies, didn't see the code edit. This indeed works, but is so ridiculously inefficient it should never count as a _good_ answer ;) Certainly _an_ answer though!

Comment: Replaced with a more efficient method.

Comment: yep, nice. Probably worth explaining why replacing `11anything` with `10...0` works though (if you understand binary, it's a trivial consequence, but it's still good to explain)

Comment: Your almost there, but what about a sequence that does not contain 11anything? What output do you get with this input? 10100

Comment: @JohnMitchell I get 10100.  Since there are no contiguous 1's.  Do you see something different?

Comment: Which is incorrect. OP requires a higher number than X, so 10100 should output 10101

Comment: So  your'e saying for `101010`  The answer would be `1000000`?

Comment: I believe so yes. Check this expansion of your answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/63364835/8194026

Comment: Careful, 1001 should output 1010. I just modified my version of the main method to include an else, which inverts 1s to 0s at the end

Comment: This update (as of 11 Aug, 19:53Z) works in all cases I checked. [Here is some Ideone to test it](https://ideone.com/SHpm4H).

Comment: This shows my original answer was incorrect. This is also much easier to solve (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Using raw binary you can use the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = 0b1000010100000000010000010000000011110000000000110000000000011011L;
    System.out.println(
            Long.toBinaryString(nextX(l)));
}

public static long nextX(long l) {
    long l2 = l >>> 1;
    long next = Long.highestOneBit(l & l2);
    long cutoff = next << 1;
    long mask = ~(cutoff - 1);
    return (l & mask) | cutoff;
}
```

prints

```
1000010100000000010000010000000010000000000000000000000000000000
```

EDIT: Based on @WJS correct way to find the smallest value just larger.

Comment: This solution prints "100010000101010", which in decimal is 17450. But "100000000000000" is the lowest possibility, with a decimal value of 16384.

Comment: Specifically, _any_ number that starts with `11...` has `10...0` as its solution, so `0b11011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011011L` so take just as long to process as `b11`: that should be a quick check and replacement. Run it in reverse: start at the MSB rather than LSB, spin until you hit a 1, then check if the next value is also 1. If so: we're done, the answer is `bitposition<<1`. If not, start the actual resolution from LSB.

Comment: The OP asks for the "next smallest" not the biggest but less than solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight expansion WJS' 99% correct answer.

There is just one thing missing, the number is not incremented if there are no consecutive 1's in the original X string.
This modification to the main method handles that.

Edit; Added an else {}. Starting from the end of the string, all digits should be inverted until a 0 is found. Then we change it to a 1 and break before passing the resulting string to WJS' codeX function.
*(codeX version does not include sb.replace(len-2,len,"11");)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "10100";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(x);

    if (!x.contains("11")) {
        for (int i = sb.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) == '0') {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '1');
                break;
            } else {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '0');
            }
        }
    }

    String result = codeX(sb.toString());

    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: What if you just replaced the last two bits with `11`.  They will either be wiped out by higher order groupings or will effect a change themselves.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work for 1001 as the output should be 1010. But I'm getting 10000

Comment: Ok I've edited this post to handle the 1001 case. That should be the full solution